# App Processing Error: Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, bitcode

I am trying to submit to Apple with bitCode enabled. Everytime i submit I am getting this email.

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "MyAPPP". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Unexpected **CFBundleExecutable Key** - The bundle at '/Payload/MyAPPP.app/Base.lproj' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the **CFBundleExecutable key** from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of **BNDL**. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

My application's info.plist has following.

[image]

Cocoa Pods for every pod has info.plist as

[image]

All Pods are here.

[image]

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, have you had any progress?

Comment: Nope no luck :(

Comment: What is weird il the `Base.lproj` reference. Do you have a localized plist somewhere? Also did you try looking for references to `CFBundleExecutable` in your whole workspace, there should be only in your main project. Also id you look inside the generated xarchive?

Comment: Yes my project is localized but info.plist is not localized via file localization, I am using string localization for it. I checked CFBundleExecutable and its present in my main info.plist, as wel as its in all the pod files. Everywhere its value is standard $(EXECUTABLE_NAME). I checked inside Archive and iPA, info.plist present at this path also, and contain same key and value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Finally I got a solution.

In my case, Info.plist file was added to Copy Bundle Resources in Build Phase. I just remove it from Copy Bundle Resources and it worked!

Comment: In my case the folder contains the plist file was added to "Copy Bundle Resources"